# Could the remote IP address be spoofed in an incoming TCP session under Windows?

Tags: windows, http, authentication, tcp

I write a HTTP small server under Windows.  Access to the server is secured with the usual HTTP auth mechanisms (I use Windows HTTP API). But I want to have no auth for localhost, i.e. local users should be able to access the server without password.

The question is: is that save?  More precisely, is it safe to trust the remote address of a TCP connection without further auth?

Assume for a moment that an adversary (Charly) is trying to send a single malicious HTTP GET to my server.  Furthermore, assume that all Windows/router firewalls ingress checks for localhost addresses let source addresses of 127.0.0.1 and [::1] pass.

So the remote address could be spoofed, but for a TCP connection we need a full three-way handshake.  Thus, a SYN-ACK is sent by Windows upon reception of the SYN.  This SYN-ACK goes nowhere, but Charly might just send an ACK shortly afterwards.  This ACK *would* be accepted *if* the ack'ed SEQ of the SYN-ACK was correct.  Afterwards, Charly can send the malicious payload since he knows the correct TCP SEQ and ACK numbers.

So all security hinges on the unpredicability of Windows' TCP outgoing initial sequence number (ISN).  I'm not sure how secure that is, how hard it is to predict next session's ISN.

Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In the scenario you are describing an attacker wouldn't get any packets from your web server. If you can use something like digest auth (where a server sends to a client a short random nonce string first and then clients uses that nonce to create an authentication hash) you'd be fine.

If installing a firewall on a system is an option, you could use a simple rule like "don't accept packets with source ip 127.0.0.1 from any interface other then loopback".

Comment: The attack works as described even if the packets never go back to the attacker if he can guess the correct ISN, if I'm correct. Re digest auth: that is part of HTTPS, I guess? And I could do HTTPS without a password, of course. So I could accept HTTPS connections from localhost with no password to solve my problem. Am I right? Re firewall: I don't want to rely on that.

Comment: As far as I know, digest authentication is not a part of HTTPS. It is a quite simple and popular authentication protocol (e.g. mod_auth_digest implements that in apache web server; asterisk uses it as well to authenticate sip peers). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication. By the way, if you can use https, that solves your problem as well, since the endpoints have to exchange a whole bunch of data just to establish a connection and a hacker would need a whole lot of luck to guess it all.